The smell of wet gypsum
Not strictly chemistry, but where does the distinctive smell of wet gypsum come from?
It is not like wet earth from geosmin.

It's from weathering (chemical, microbial, other) of gypsum ($\ce{CaSO4\cdot 2H2O}$) and mostly arises from the evolution of $\ce{H2S}$.
That said, there are numerous other sulfur-containing compounds involved in gypsum decomposition which can/will contribute to the aroma.
See Gypsum Drywall Odor Landfills Jan 2002 Update from the EPA for more details.
Geosmin is a terpene and doesn't contain sulfur so while subjective descriptions of "earthiness" and the like may be warranted, they do not arise from similar chemical processes involving sulfur-containing compounds.
